# flutter is it ok to use many video player controller?

Tags: flutter

Let’s say I have 30 videos to play. In this case, is it safe or ok to prepare 30 video player controller for each video? Is there any possibility that cause problems by doing it? If so, what kind of problems there would be?

Comment: 30 files and one player surely ?

Comment: I’m sorry what do you mean?

Comment: why would you want to create 30 instances of the player?

Comment: Because I want to prepare video to be played as quick as possible. Make sense?

Comment: set up the video player in initState(). And pass the file paths as needed.